# Xubuntu 13.04 Panel

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, panel

I have Xubuntu 13.04 installed on my laptop. I uninstalled Abiword and installed LibreOffice. My question is how do I add Writer, Calc and Impress to the panel? I've gone into add new items but it doesn't show LibreOffice. I've tried dragging a dropping but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did.

All you have to do is click on the Applications Menu--> Office, and just drag the one's you want to the panel.

[image]

You'll get a popup that asks you if you want to create launcher, just click it.

[image]

And just drag them to the panel.  That's it

[image]

Or Right click on the panel-->Panel-->Add new Items

[image]

And choose to add a launcher

[image]

Right click on the newly created icon, and choose properties.  And then click on the + sign.

[image]

Scroll down until you see Libreoffice, highlight the items that you want, you can multiple choose using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key.  Once done click on close.

[image]
[image]

And you will see the icons on the panel.

[image]